# Query XML to pull out one record and bind data to individual text blocks

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm new at this so bear with me.  Using C# and LINQ, I am trying to pull out one record from an XML file and I want to bind it's Elements and Attributes to individual textblocks.

Lets say I have this xml file named Test.xml:

```
<Data>
  <Test id=1>
     <Text>"First Record"</Text>
  </Test>
  <Test id=2>
     <Text>"Second Record"</Text>
  </Test>
<Data>
```

I want to pass in a variable for the id so i can pull out that records information and bind it to individual textblocks

```
var r = 2  // just hardcoding for the example

XDocument d = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");

var q = from t in d.Descendants("Test")
where t.Attribute("id").Value == r  
select new
{
   id = t.Attribute("id").Value,
   text = t.Element("text").Value
}
```

Now I would like to bind "id" and "text" to indivual Text blocks

```
idTextBlock.Text = id
textTextBlock.Text = text
```

This of course throws up all sorts of errors about id and text "not existing in this context". All the examples I have seen have simply put the output lumped to a single string on the console which doesn't help me.  I am really new (2nd week) to programming so I may be doing this completely wrong. ANY assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess q.id and q.text should work fine when binding.

Comment: Now I get this error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Use var q = (from t in d.Descendants("Test")
where t.Attribute("id").Value == r  
select new
{
   id = t.Attribute("id").Value,
   text = t.Element("text").Value
}).DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected XML you've provided to get query below worked.

```
int r = 2;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");            
string id = r.ToString();
string text = xdoc.Descendants("Test")
                  .Where(d => d.Attribute("id").Value == id)                
                  .Descendants("Text")
                  .Select(n => n.Value)
                  .SingleOrDefault();
```

---

**Corrected XML:** (Closed `Data` tag, id attribute value enclosed in double quotes)

```xml
<Data>   
  <Test id="1"> 
     <Text>"First Record"</Text>   
  </Test>   
  <Test id="2">
      <Text>"Second Record"</Text>   
  </Test> 
</Data>
```

Comment: hmm... now I'm getting a "sequence contains no elements" error.  It doesn't show up till it is ran though.

Comment: Have you used XML I've provided and query without any changes? By design LINQ `Single()` will throw such exception, but with a given data it should return an entry, you can consider using `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: See updated LINQ query, as a previous one it returns `"SecondRecord"` and would not be fail if recor was not found since used `SingleOrDefault()` but again for the given XML it return the value

Comment: AHA!  it turns out I had my numbers in my xml formatted slightly different.  I was using "002" (for formating reasons) versus 2 and I guess an int will trim off leading zeros 00 so no records where matching the query.  Thanks this works great.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just wanted you to know I tried to up rank your answer but I don't have enough rep points yet.  Thanks again.  Your code was really straight forward so it was really easy to understand what was going on.

Comment: Right, you need rep 15 to upvote. Do not worry about that, all is fine!